# How can I display multiple images as a slider in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

How can I display multiple features images on pages as a slider in WordPress?

I am using dynamic features images plugins to add multiple feature images. But unable to retrieve that images in the page. Any one can help me to solve it. 
Using:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail($current_page_id, 'full'))
{   
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($current_page_id); 
    echo $image_id;
    $image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full', true);    

    if(isset($image_thumb[0]) && !empty($image_thumb[0]))
    {
        $pp_page_bg = $image_thumb[0];
    }
    //print_r ($pp_page_bg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Dynamic Featured Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/) plugin then you need to use code defined by this plugin owner.

You can get images by calling this function:

```
$images_loop = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images([$postId (optional)])
```

`$images_loop` will return an array with image properties then you can loop this variable and use the slider.

Check this [link](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/Dynamic-Featured-Image/wiki/API#getting-image-title-alt-and-caption-attributes) also to understand in detail.

Hope this will helpful for you.